# How to query Elasticsearch from C# via HTTP?

Tags: c#, http, elasticsearch

I am trying to write code in C# for PUT and GET to my elasticsearch data.
I typed code for PUT like this, and it seems that it works:

```
string url = "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/";

JsonDocFormat json = new JsonDocFormat()
{
   name = "John"
};

string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   client.UploadString(url, "POST", s);
}
```

But I can't write code for this GET:

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query" : {
       "match" : {
            "name" : "john"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
string url_req = "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?pretty";

string s1 = "{\"query\": {\"match\": { \"name\" : \"john\" }}}";

string s_req = url_req + s1;

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    Console.Write(client.DownloadString(s_req));
}
```

But this code returned same output as for this GET:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
```

It did not throw any error, but it absolutely ignored json body at the end of URL. I want to write this without any external package (as NEST or Elasticsearch.NET), just with HTTP.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: shouldn't string s1 be "{\"query\": {\"match\": { \"name\" : \"john\" }}}" ?

Comment: Sorry just a mistake.. I tried to make it easier to understand. In my original document I use field ´text´ but here I renamed it to ´name´ but I forgot to overwrite that particular ´text´ in that piece of code. But my problem is still current.

Comment: Is it possible to explain what does 'pretty' refers to in your url request ?

Comment: @EmnaJaoua https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to do the same also using HttpClient library (since I need to work with .Net Client 2.2 framework). I am defining the url and credentials through client.BaseAddress and client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization but when I get the response through response = await client.GetAsync(path), the response is not successful so I was not able to make a request. I am using exactly the same query format as yours (string s). Any useful links for help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution for my question is in this code

```
string url_req = "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?pretty";

string s = "{\"query\": {\"match\": { \"name\" : \"john\" }}}";

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    Console.Write(client.UploadString(url_req, "POST", s));
}
```

Comment: Your answer used a POST verb. For security reasons, I want to find a solution with the GET verb. GNU/Linux cURL will allow you to send message bodies with the GET verb so I don't understand why so many other WebRequest tools don't allow it. From what I've read elsewhere on SO, sending a request body with a GET request is "weird", but the standard doesn't specifically disallow it.